# Improve performance of storing millions of pictures into database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have millions of pictures (each picture around 7Kb) located in a folder temp (under Windows Server 2012) and I want to store them in a SQL Server database.

What I am doing so far is:

- Searching for files using: `foreach (var file in directory.EnumerateFiles())`
- Reading each file as a binary data: `byte[] data = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\temp\\" + file.Name);`
- Saving each binary data using SQLCommand:

  ```
  using (SqlCommand savecmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE myTable set downloaded=1,imagecontent=@imagebinary,insertdate='" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + "' where imagename='" + file.Name.Replace(".jpg", "") + "'", connection))
  {
      savecmd.Parameters.Add("@imagebinary", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1).Value = data;
      savecmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
  ```
- Each picture inserted successfully is deleted from temp folder

This kind of fetching for a file and go and store it into database does not take a lot of time because `myTable` has a clustered index on `imagename`.
But when we talk about millions and millions of files, it takes a huge amount of time to complete this whole operation.

Is there a way to improve on this way of working? For example, instead of storing file by file, store ten by ten, or thousand by thousand? Or using threads? What is the best suggestion for this kind of problem?

Comment: How often do you need to do that? Is that a one time action?

Comment: No i need to do it permanently, the action of storing pictures should not stop (there is another server that download files into temp folder).

Comment: You could use `Task.Factory.StartNew(data => SaveFileToDb(data))`

Comment: Well, I think if both Services are running nonestop - this would be more than enough, because if your other Service is adding files to this folder, and you are reading from it - there will never be realy many files left in the folder, which are going to be written to the db, so there should be no need for Multithreading - am I wrong? By the way, you could ask the data kraken Google, FB etc. ;) They know how to store new data nonestop :D

Comment: Well then I suggest you run @TimSchmelter MultiThreading approach for Initial run, then swap back to None-multithreading.

Comment: You should batch multiple updates into one call to reduce the roundtrip.

Comment: so you suggest to create a stored procedure to do for example thousand updates per database call? if so this is the only solution i tought of, cuz the database call cost a lot of milliseconds, but i am not sure if on the database side, the thousand updates gonna cost less with a very important difference when we talk about massive data.

Comment: You need to figure out what makes it slow first. Is that limited by disk read IO? Maybe by database? If not by these two then you need to use async (both to read files and write to database) or use multiple threads.

Comment: maybe you can just use FileTable https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929144.aspx and replace your binary files?

Answer (score 0):

You should think about indexing your image storage by an identifier, not the big nvarchar() field you use for your image name "name.jpg". 
It is way more faster to search by an indexed ID.
So i would suggest to split your table in two tables.

The first one holding an primary unique ID (indexed) and the ImageBinary.

The second table holds foreign Key ID reference, insertdate, downloaded, image name (PK if needed and indexed).

By integrating views or stored procedures, you can then still insert/update via a single call to the DB, but read entries by just looking up the picture by ID directly on the first table.

To know which ID to call, you can cache the IDs in memory (and load them from table 2 at startup or so).

This should fasten the reading of pictures.

If your main problem is to bulk insert and update all the pictures, you should consider using a user define table type and bulk merge the data into the DB
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx

If you can switch your logic to just inserting pictures, not updating, you could use the .net class "SqlBulkCopy" to fasten things up.

Hope this helps,
Greetings

Comment: MyTable got an Id and this is id happens to be the name of the pictures. MyTable got millions of entries and it is well indexed, ClusteredIndex on Imagename (the Id) and non clusteredIndex on downloaded column (for other purposes). Any kind of query on this table takes 0seconde to run. And i am trying to update image pictures on myTable.

Comment: each time there is a picture located on temp folder i need to updated it on Database, this operation does not take a lot of time normally, but it happens that temp folder already contains millions and millions of pictures and this whole operation takes a lot of time to end.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your issue isn't the database, but FileIO finding the files themselves for deletion. I'd suggest splitting the temp file into multiple smaller files. If there's good distribution across the alphabet, you could have a directory for each letter (and numbers if there are some of those as well) and put the files into the directory that matches their first letter. This would make finding and deleting the files much faster. This could even be extended to have a few hundred files using the first 3 characters of the filename. This would help significantly with millions of files.